# Jenkins build triggered twice when merging branch

Tags: jenkins, build, continuous-integration

A project with Jenkins integration has selected option: Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket. Everything works as expected until some other branch is merged to master. In this case Jenkins triggers two builds. Has anyone experienced this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced the same issue only for *master* branch, like you. The solution that worked was to update `Build Triggers` configuration of the job that was triggered twice by leaving `Poll SCM -> Schedule` text box empty (no Cron expression entered). So the proper configuration is to only mark the two  trigger options:

1. `[✓]` *Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket*
2. `[✓]` *Poll SCM* (**leave the *Schedule* text box empty**)

[image]

In case [Jenkins Job DSL](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin) plugin is used for generating the build job, it should contain proper `triggers` block (which corresponds to the above screen):

```
triggers {
  bitbucketPush()
  scm('') // empty Cron expression string
}
```