# Jenkins starts Duplicate builds from same commit Multibranch pipeline

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket-server

We're seeing multiple builds of our Jenkins multi-branch pipeline being triggered by the same merge commit in Bitbucket.

One build is marked triggered by a: *"Branch event at "*

The other by a: *"commit notification "*

We have our Jenkins urls setup in a plugin

> Bitbucket Server Webhook to Jenkins

and have a our trigger in the Jenkinsfile setup as follows:

```
triggers {
    pollSCM ""
    cron "H 0 * * *"
}
```

There seem to be a couple of old [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40633735/duplicate-builds-triggered-on-jenkins-multibranch-pipeline) that unfortunately don't have concrete answers.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46561344/jenkins-build-triggered-twice-when-merging-branch. Maybe it will help you as the problem is similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like both the: `Branch API Plugin` and the `Git client plugin` were sending events to Jenkins that triggered a build.

We solved the issue by suppressing automatic triggering.

This can be done either in the UI simply by going to your job, selecting configure from the left then adding the property

> Suppress automatic SCM triggering.

Alternatively for a code solution (which I ended up using) add it to the seedjob.groovy as follows:

```
multibranchPipelineJob("${service.name}-build") {
    // ... unrelated code omitted

    configure { project ->
        project.remove(project / 'sources' / 'data' / 'jenkins.branch.BranchSource' / 'strategy' / 'properties')
        def s = project / 'sources' / 'data' / 'jenkins.branch.BranchSource' / 'strategy' {
            properties(class: 'java.util.Arrays$ArrayList') {
                a(class: 'jenkins.branch.NoTriggerBranchProperty') {
                    'jenkins.branch.NoTriggerBranchProperty' ''
                }             
            }
        }
    }

}
```

*UPDATE:*

It seems like Julian's answer worked but had a bug where it didn't automatically trigger pushes to feature branches. In our Jenkinsfile we added:

```
properties([overrideIndexTriggers(true)])
```

Which ensures git commit still triggers a build despite NoTriggerBranchProperty in our seedjob.

Answer (score 3):

We were using Bitbucket with Jenkins integration and had this issue. Our problem was that on the Bitbucket webhook we had selected notifications from push and from PR. This configuration created a Job with the branch name and a second job called PR-XXX when the PR was created.

Maybe this is the reason?

Comment: Our problem was that two plugins both sent events that triggered a build. See my answer above for more info on how we solved it.